# VS Code not opening with bash shell - (code:222398): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:20:07.940: cannot open display:

Tags: linux, bash, shell, virtual-machine

So I'm trying to open a project in vscode on a linux virtual machine but have no such luck.

Initially, when I connect to the VM it's using C Shell and works fine.

But once I switch to bash using the 'bash' command it stops.

EG. When trying the following

```
code --verbose project
```

I get

```
(code:226543): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:38:02.399: cannot open display:
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it refers to the fact that your server has no desktop (GUI) and you are trying to open a graphical application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DISPLAY` environment variable is not being set. Are there some settings from the many [csh startup files](https://www.mankier.com/1/tcsh#Description-Startup_and_shutdown) you forgot to replicate into the bash startup (~/.bash_profile)?

Just as an aside, I am *extremely* curious what kind of Linux distribution both uses tcsh by default AND neglects to maintain the POSIX shell profile.